# ¿Cómo pasar el array a una variable en PHP?

Tags: php

Digamos que tengo este código:

```
$coches = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");

foreach ($coches as $key => $coche) {
    // Funcciona
    echo $coche .'<br/>';
}

// No funciona
echo '<hr>'. $coches;
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener una variable llamada `$coches` para representarla con un `echo`?

Comment: que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente?  no te funciona de la segunda manera pues estas imprimiendo el objeto array. el primero si te funciona por que posición por posición. tu pregunta es como imprimir un array sin el for?

Comment: Puede ser con el for pero necesito tener esos valores en una variable como si fuese una frase normal, para posteriormente utilizarla en mi código.

Comment: quieres poner todo el array en un solo string? usa json_encode

Comment: Quiero hacerlo en PHP .. no es posible ? Si es posible en json_encode, podrías ponerlo en un ejemplo ...

Comment: La sugerencia de @Luis era el camino más corto. Yo sobrecompliqué las cosas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es juntar todas tus palabras del array en una sola variable string, puedes usar la función `implode()`

```
<?php

$array = array('apellido', 'email', 'teléfono');
$separado_por_espacios= implode(" ", $array);

echo $separado_por_espacios; // apellido email teléfono

?>
```

Este ejemplo fue tomado de la pagina oficial de PHP.

Comment: Funciona, gracias